# responsive tab menu with centered dropdown area

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, accessibility

This is what it should look like:
[image]

There is a tab-menu and a dropdown area. This should always have the same position (but different content and the respective tab choosen) as in the picture. Meaning it should always be as wide as the tabs(-menu).

But I can not figure out how:

- to get this responsive
- how to have the dropdown area stay where it is
- how to style the subitems (in the dropdown area)

Here is what I got so far (sorry for the huge css it is not cleaned yet!), the menu starts at line 1559.

http://jsfiddle.net/pxpHw/

How do I do this properly?

THANKS!

code:

```
// css

nav {
    cursor: default;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background:green;
    z-index: 100;
    max-width: 60em;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu li ul {
    display: none;
    /*display: block;*/
    padding-top: 3px;
}

#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

#menu li ul li {
    background-color: #2F2D49;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 60em;
    min-height: 30em;
    position: absolute;
}

#menu li ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu li ul li:hover {
    background-color: #232323;
}
```

Comment: I`m not sure what you are trying to do in the your fiddle. I think you should look into this redhat site for better understanding of how it is done. http://in.redhat.com/. for better understanding use firebug on firefox and check it  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to get the responsive design

Check the following links

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

http://mediaqueri.es/

Thanks
AB

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for: (Columns and Layout tab)
http://codecanyon.net/item/css3-full-responsive-dropdown-menu/full_screen_preview/4528828